# i itry to fetch data but i have error : type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: flutter, dart

hello i'm new in flutter.....

i 'm trying to fetch api data into Text

i dont have int, but flutter have error with int...

what can i do?

i have no idea,,,,,

i'm also lacking practice...too......

this is `class info`
`class info` have json file information
i annotation some codes becase of error
but they don't change...

help me please... :(

error name is **type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'**

```
class Info {
//final int id;
final String name;
final String description;
final String price;
//final String user_id;


Info({  this.name, this.description, this.price  });

factory Info.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
return Info(

  //id : int.parse(json['id']),
  name: json['useName'],
  description: json['description'],
  price: json['price'],

  //   //id: json['id'] ,
  //   name: json['userName'],
  // description: json['description'],
  //   //price: json['balance'],
  //  // user_id: json['user_id']


);
}

}
```

this is main....

```html
 

void main() {
  runApp(BorrowApis(  info: fetchInfo(),
  ),);
}

class BorrowApis extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<Info> info;
  const BorrowApis({this.info});



          child: FutureBuilder<Info>(
              future: info,
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasData){
                  return Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      //Text('상품id'+snapshot.data.id.toString(),),
                      Text('상품명'+snapshot.data.name.toString(),),
                      Text('설명'+snapshot.data.description.toString(),),
                      //Text('가격'+snapshot.data.price.toString(),

                    ],
                  );
                } else if(snapshot.hasError){
                  print(snapshot.error);
                  return Text("error");
                }
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
        

Future<Info> fetchInfo()async{
  final response =
  await http.get('http://172.30.1.17:8000/api/lend_product_list');
  if(response.statusCode == 200){

    // return  json.decode(response.body)['info'].map((data)=>Info.fromJson(data))
    // .toList();

    return  json.decode(response.body)['info'];
```

this is json file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGqH6.png)

Comment: The question is a bit messy here, but can you please add the exact error which is thrown, to your post? This will better help understand what's going on here

Comment: Can you add your response (JSON) to the question?

Comment: Might there be a typo here?  `name: json['useName'],`  I would expect it to be `userName` as it was in your comment.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz oh thank you it is mistake when i write question :(

Comment: @fartem i add json file! thank you :))))

Comment: @MikiMints main has error...

Comment: Seems like you might be taking the entire list from the JSON response as the object, and trying to convert that to an `Info` object. I would guess that the error complains about you trying to access fields of `info` with string keys, but since you're passing a list object, it expects an integer key.

Comment: @MikiMints then.. how can i add `info`? i understand your comment, but i cant apply your answer in code......  i'm just newbie flutter.....

Comment: Your json file is a list of info objects, but when you call `json.decode` in your code, you apply it to the entire list. Try either applying it to a specific item (for example, `response.body[0]`) or instead returning a list of `Info` objects and then using map to call decode on each of them.